# How can I append a string to an array stored in an object, in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I want to use an obj->log($msg) function to store strings, and then later dump them

**UPDATED:**

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;
package obj;


  sub log{
      my($self,$log_info) = @_;

      push(@{$self->{log}},$log_info);  

  }

  sub showlog{

    my($self) = @_;
    my $counter = 0;
    my @log= @{$self->{log}};

    print '<div id="log" class="_view _debug"><h1>Log Data</h1>';


        foreach my $i (@log) {
            $counter++;
          print '<div class="item',(($counter%2)?' alt':''),'"><em class="tag">',$counter,'</em><pre>';
          print(Dumper($i));
          print $i;
          print '</pre></div>';
        }
      print '</div>';
  }
```

but I can't figure out how to append new items to $self->{log} -- I come from PHP land so this is a bit painful.

It would be nice if I could have log be any sort of data, and just dump it out, array, hash or scalar... is there a way to do this?

Comment: That doesn't look quite right,  is $self->{log} an array reference?  If so, you should use @{$self->{log}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashes values must be scalars. If you want to store multiple values in hash value, you'll need to find a way of placing multiple values in a scalar. A way that would work well here involves storing a reference to an array in the hash value:

```
$self->{log} = [];  # Optional because of autovivification.
```

Then place the multiple values in the referenced array:

```
push @{ $self->{log} }, $log_info;
```

One would iterate over the values as follows:

```
for my $entry (@{ $self->{log} }) {
```

If you want to use index for `$i % 2`, you can use:

```
my $log = $self->{log};
for my $i (0..$#$log) {
   my $entry = $log->[$i];
   ...
}
```

---

Note: Since 5.14.0,

```
push $self->{log}, ...;
```

is mostly equivalent to

```
push @{ $self->{log} }, ...;
```

Perl 5.14 is pretty new, so you might want to stay away from that for unless you're just coding for yourself.

Comment: @nodebunny, added a way of getting rid of `$counter`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though `$self->{log}` is an array reference.  As of Perl 5.14.0, it's safe to `push` onto array references, but otherwise, you'll want to de-reference the array reference and do: `push(@{$self->{log}},$log_info);`.  Similarly, you'll want to dereference when assigning to `@log` by doing `my @log=@{$self->{log}}` (and by the way, you have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your script, right?).

Take a look at [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

You'll probably also find [`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.131/Dumper.pm) to be handy for printing out complicated data structures.  If you want to know everything that's in your log, you can just have `use Data::Dumper;` at the beginning of your script and then do `print Dumper($self->{log}) . "\n";` (no need to de-reference!).

Comment: Okay, just making sure, since I didn't see a `my @log` in the first place in which `@log` appears in the code snippet.  :)

Comment: Well I'd like to have an array or hash or scalar in the log and use dumper to render those, but I want to wrap that output with a pre tag and some classes in html, I'm not having any lucky passing arrays to my log function

Comment: Yeah, taking a closer look at `show_log`, I'm not sure what you mean by `$.%2`.

Comment: No, your looping variable is `$i` (which is an element of `@log`).  What, exactly are you trying to print out with each iteration?  What are the dynamic parts of the string that you're trying to print?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3385/discussion-between-nodebunny-and-jack-maney)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
  package Logger;

  # create a logger object
  sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;
    my @messages;

    my $self = {
        log => \@messages,
    };
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
  }

  # add a message to the log
  sub append {
    my $self = shift;
    my $message = shift;
    push ( @{$self->{log}}, $message );
  }

  # print the log
  sub printlog {
    my $self = shift;
    foreach my $msg ( @{$self->{log}} ){
      print "$msg\n";
    }
  }
```

Comment: this didnt work with use strict - did you mean : foreach my $msg ( @{$self->{log}} )

Answer (score 1):

You could `use`[`autobox::Core`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autobox%3a%3aCore).

```
use autobox::Core;
...
$self->{log}->push( $log_info );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Moose.

```
package Logger;

use Moose; ### Enables strict/warnings

has '_log_ref' => => (
        traits  => ['Array'],
        is      => 'ro',
        isa     => 'ArrayRef[Str]',
        default => sub { [] },
        handles => {
            _log_contents    => 'elements',
            log              => 'push',
        },
    );

sub showlog {
    my($self) = @_;
    my $counter = 0;

    print '<div id="log" class="_view _debug"><h1>Log Data</h1>';


    for my $i ($self->_log_contents()) {
          $counter++;
          print '<div class="item',(($counter%2)?' alt':''),'"><em class="tag">',$counter,'</em><pre>';
          print(Dumper($i));
          print $i;
          print '</pre></div>';
     }
     print '</div>';
}
```